# Select from table where negative float has exact value

Tags: mysql

I'm sure this is an easy one, because I can't find a solution very quickly, but...
I try to select from a database where a float value is negative.

I tried:

```
SELECT balance FROM data WHERE balance = -116.26
SELECT balance FROM data WHERE balance = "-116.26"
SELECT balance FROM data WHERE balance = -116,26
SELECT balance FROM data WHERE balance = "-116,26"
```

Only the following gave me a result:

```
SELECT balance FROM data WHERE balance < 0
```

but I need to query the exact value -116.26.

The balance was created like this:
`balance float DEFAULT NULL`

I expected the output not to be empty.
And for sure, yes, the value does exist.

Comment: Is the value in the table actually -116.26 ? Since it is a float, there could be a floating point rounding error that you may have to account for.

Comment: Yes it is. I copy the exact value from the `SELECT balance FROM data WHERE balance < 0` query to the `SELECT balance FROM data WHERE balance = -116.26`query and get no result.

Comment: Try this: `SELECT balance FROM data WHERE CAST(balance AS DECIMAL) = CAST(-116.26 AS DECIMAL)`

Comment: Do `select * from data` and show us your results.